# 'localhost' not working on browser

Tags: java, servlets, tomcat7

When I start Tomcat from command line and then do

```
http://localhost
```

the Tomcat welcome page is showing, but when I start Tomcat from Eclipse and then do the same, I get this error:
    description The requested resource is not available.
But when I access my application

```
    http://localhost/Servlet_Test/HelloWorld
```

from the browser, it works fine.

Is localhost supposed to display Tomcat's welcome page even when tomcat is run on IDE or no?

Comment: What port is tomcat listening on? Whenever I run tomcat, I specify a port, ex 8080, so when I go to the website it is http://localhost:8080. Then it can pick up the index.html file

Answer (score 1):

Double click on the Tomcat server entry in the Servers tab, you'll get the server configuration. At the left column, under Server Locations, select Use Tomcat installation (note, when it is grayed out, read the section leading text! ;) ). This way Eclipse will take full control over Tomcat, this way you'll also be able to access the default Tomcat homepage with the Tomcat Manager when running from inside Eclipse. I only don't see how that's useful while developing using Eclipse.

**NOTE: Simply because the Tomcat homepage is not in the work space metadata the Tomcat homepage is not one of the Eclipse projects.**

Below steps to change server location.

1. Right click on my tomcat server in "Servers" view, select "Properties…"
2. In the "General" panel, click on the "Switch Location" button
3. The "Location: [workspace metadata]" bit should have been replaced by something else.
4. Open (or close and reopen) the Overview screen for the server.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! It is grayed out for me. Sorry, what does this mean? "note, when it is grayed out, read the section leading text! ;) "

Comment: Read sentence in bracket e.g: takes control of Tomcat installation.

Comment: What you have to do is just follow give 4 steps.

Comment: Sorry, I am not understanding what you mean :( How do I enable the grayed out section? Which 4 steps are you referring to?

Comment: 1. Right Click on Server (In Eclipse) 2. Select General 3. Click on Switch Location and make sure your Location is /server/TomcatVx.x Server at localhost.server. Once you save changes restart your tomcat in eclipse and try to access tomcat home

Comment: Thank you. I followed the steps. The location metadata got replaced as you'd mentioned and I restarted Tomcat. But still it's grayed out :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61313/discussion-between-prasanna-and-mind-peace).

Answer (score 0):

For your page to be the first, you need to define it as being one of the entries in the welcome list:

http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/HowTo

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Answer (score -1):

You will have to specify the port number as well:
Change`localhost` to `localhost:8080/<servletname>/path`

Hope this helps.